# Solving Laplace's equation on the unit disc using the method of images

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following problem:

> Solve $\nabla^{2} u= 0$ inside the unit disc, subject to $u(1,\theta) = \delta (\theta - \alpha)$.

I am familiar with the method of images but only for simpler domains. I have been given that the image point of $x_0$ inside the domain is $y_0 = \dfrac{x_0}{|x_0|^2}$.

The solution is apparently

$$ u (r, \theta) = \dfrac{1-r^2}{2\pi\left(1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta - \alpha)\right)}$$

Any help would be appreciated!